# UITextView text background colour

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, core-text

I am trying to get a transparent UITextView, and I know how to set it. What I also want is like a coloured background right under the text that has been shown. Again the text view background will set the entire view rectangle to a given colour, what I want is colour just under the text. Any easy way of achieving such thing?

Comment: Check out this TextViewHighlighter https://gist.github.com/onmyway133/c1fb7f8bf26a0bd144a3

Answer (score 7):

From what I can tell you're trying to accomplish a highlighting effect on the text. If this is the case you could use NSAttributedString. It allows you to set the background color of the text and not the view background.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Test String"];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor lightGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 11)];
```

Then set the attributedText property on your UITextView:

```
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: This is almost it. The problem is the text is shorter than the full line, and the highlight goes till the end of the line. Can I round the corners of the highlight?